# How does the quarantine of anti-virus/malware software work?

Tags: malware, virus, antivirus, antimalware, sandbox

What is the quarantine of antivirus software? Is it just some strict user/group rights and changing file extension or is it an actual moving the file(s) to a virtual environment?

How is this software preventing a virus from executing or breaking out of such a sandbox/quarantine?

Comment: I know it's not an exact match for the question, but I think the accepted answer is exactly what you're asking about

Comment: Also related, for the same reasons: [Can AV software make sure quarantined files never get executed?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/129097/32746)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many AV function the same way but may have different *specific* mechanisms of action. In general they work like this:

> When MBAM removes an item such as a file or a Registry entry and
>   "quarantines" the item, it is removed from its original location and
>   stored in a protected container. Both the removed item and it location
>   are stored in the container in a way that the file is rendered inert
>   and the location of where it was removed from is also restored. Thus
>   if it is deemed to be a False Positive declaration, the item removed
>   (file or Registry entry) can be restored to its original and working
>   state. If however the item(s) are deemed to be justly removed for
>   malicious activity, the quarantine can be "dumped" such that can not
>   be restored and the container no longer holds any more quarantined
>   items or you can choose to be selective on what is dumped from
>   quarantine.

[SOURCE](https://forums.malwarebytes.org/topic/106957-what-actually-happens-to-quarantined-items/)

There is also [another post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64443/can-malware-be-dangerous-even-when-quarantined) on the InfoSec SE that has some additional info:

> In most anti-virus programs, the quarantine files are stored in
>   internal binary formats. Since there is no physical connection between
>   the infector file to your system (your anti-virus program works as the
>   storage format is also a plus point), it is not dangerous.